# Ошибка подключения к SqlServer 2014 через EF

Tags: sql-server

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

При отладки приложения в VS2017C выводит ошибку подключения к MSSQL2014.
До утра работало все гуд, а потом что то начало выводить ошибку.

Comment: какая строка подключения у вас?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте решение из английской версии SO - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2231500/error-connecting-to-all-of-my-sql-servers

Запустите cliconfg.exe (C:\WINDOWS\system32\cliconfg.exe), на вкладке General проверьте отключенные протоколы, у них должен быть статус "force protocol encryption".
Если этот флажок установлен для любого из этих значений, VS, вероятно, пытается принудительно зашифровать соединение.